# Illegal string offset Warning in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am facing error/Warning Illegal string offset

I have check all my code but no error reason found.
with below function my theme style is working the code is written in word press theme in the function.php.

> ( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
>   ( ! ) Warning: Illegal string offset 'face' in F:\wamp\www\wordpress-3.6.1-newsduke\wp-content\themes\hotnews\functions\theme-functions.php on line 140

```
 function freshthemes_theme_styles() {

        /* Google fonts array */
        $google_fonts = array_keys( freshthemes_typography_get_google_fonts() );

        /* Define all the options that possibly have a unique Google font */
        $body_font = ft_get_option('body_font', 'Arial, Helvetica, san-serif');
        $heading_font = ft_get_option('heading_font', 'Arial, Helvetica, san-serif');
        $menu_nav_font = ft_get_option('menu_nav_font', 'Arial, Helvetica, san-serif');

        /* Get the font face for each option and put it in an array */
        $selected_fonts = array(
            $body_font['face'],
            $heading_font['face'],
            $menu_nav_font['face'],
        );

        /* Remove any duplicates in the list */
        $selected_fonts = array_unique($selected_fonts);

        /* If it is a Google font, go ahead and call the function to enqueue it */
        foreach ( $selected_fonts as $font ) {
            if ( in_array( $font, $google_fonts ) ) {
                freshthemes_typography_enqueue_google_font($font);
            }
        }

        // Register our styles.
        wp_register_style('main', get_stylesheet_uri(), false, THEME_VERSION, 'all');
        wp_register_style('prettyPhoto', THEME_DIR . '/stylesheets/prettyPhoto.css', false, THEME_VERSION, 'all');
        wp_register_style('responsive', THEME_DIR . '/stylesheets/responsive.css', false, THEME_VERSION, 'all');
        wp_register_style('custom-style', THEME_DIR . '/functions/framework/frontend/custom-style.css', false, filemtime(THEME_PATH . '/functions/framework/frontend/custom-style.css'), 'all');

        // Enqueue them.
        wp_enqueue_style('main');
        wp_enqueue_style('custom-style');
        wp_enqueue_style('prettyPhoto');
        wp_enqueue_style('responsive');
    }
```

Comment: I find it hard to believe that the `internet and search engines` didn't list anything for `Warning: Illegal string offset`?

Comment: Sorry for this but no any helpful answer was found

Comment: What does var_dump($body_font, $heading_font, $menu_nav_font) shows?

Comment: @anupam var_dump showing "  string 'Arial, Helvetica, san-serif' (length=27)  " three times.

Comment: @ShagunSood Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$selected_fonts = array(
    $body_font,
    $heading_font,
    $menu_nav_font,
);
```

As $body_font, $heading_font and $menu_nav_font are string, using those as array will produce the warnings.

**EDIT:**

To be more generic:

```
$selected_fonts = array(
    is_array($body_font) && isset($body_font['face']) ? $body_font['face'] : $body_font,
    is_array($heading_font) && isset($heading_font['face']) ? $heading_font['face'] : $heading_font,
    is_array($menu_nav_font) && isset($menu_nav_font['face']) ? $menu_nav_font['face'] : $menu_nav_font,
);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$selected_fonts = array(
    $body_font['face'],
    $heading_font['face'],
    $menu_nav_font['face'],
);
```

One or more of these variables is a string, which you are trying to access like an array, this  only works if you access it with a numeric key slammer than `strlen-1`

To confirm this, do a `var_dump($body_font, $heading_font, $menu_nav_font)` too check which one is not actually an array, but a string.

Comment: var_dump showing " string 'Arial, Helvetica, san-serif' (length=27) " three times.

Comment: well, then my assumption was correct, and you have an illegal offset because you are trying to access a `string` as if it were an `array`

Comment: sure give me your email address, and a list of your tasks and I'll email you the complete project by tomorrow noon, Sir.