# Warning: Illegal string offset 'face' in Wordpress Blackfyre

Tags: php, wordpress

This is the code that I am working with -

```
if ( !function_exists( 'blackfyre_options_typography_google_fonts' ) ) {
    function blackfyre_options_typography_google_fonts() {
        $all_google_fonts = array_keys( blackfyre_options_typography_get_google_fonts() );
        // Define all the options that possibly have a unique Google font
        $google_font = of_get_option('google_font', 'Rokkitt, serif');
        $google_mixed = of_get_option('google_mixed', false);
        $google_mixed_2 = of_get_option('google_mixed_2', 'Arvo, serif');
        // Get the font face for each option and put it in an array
        $selected_fonts = array(
            $google_font['face'],    - 1035 line
            $google_mixed['face'],   
            $google_mixed_2['face'] );   - 1037 line
        // Remove any duplicates in the list
        $selected_fonts = array_unique($selected_fonts);
        // Check each of the unique fonts against the defined Google fonts
        // If it is a Google font, go ahead and call the function to enqueue it
        foreach ( $selected_fonts as $font ) {
            if ( in_array( $font, $all_google_fonts ) ) {
                blackfyre_options_typography_enqueue_google_font($font);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

These are the error messages I receive -

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'face' in /home/imposing/public_html/wp-content/themes/blackfyre/functions.php on line 1035
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'face' in /home/imposing/public_html/wp-content/themes/blackfyre/functions.php on line 1037

I need help to resolve this error and/or point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I Had the same issue like i stated in my previous comment by i fixed it by changing the code in extra-functions.php, line 105 - 107, to:

```
$selected_fonts = array(
 $google_font,
 $google_mixed,
 $google_mixed_2 );
```

as found in
[Illegal string offset Warning in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18957409/illegal-string-offset-warning-in-wordpress%20.))

I hope that solves it for you too.

Cheers.